# How do I make a window move to the left half of my screen and another window move to the right half?

Tags: macos, window-manager, ui, windows

On Windows 8, I type <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> and the current window becomes full-height and half the screen width and moves to the left. If I type <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>, the current window does the same except moves to the right.

This is so incredibly helpful. Is there a mechanism to do the same for Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Cinch and SizeUp apps to do that.

http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/

http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/

Comment: This looks perfect. Is there a free alternative?

Comment: I do not know any free apps, but the app DoublePane cost $4.99. It's same as Cinch or BetterSnapTool at just $1.99.                                                       https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12                                                       http://5amcode.com/

Comment: I ended up with Spectacle, seems to work perfect and is free.

Comment: Link to Spectacle: https://www.spectacleapp.com/